# A result of Steel on characterizing lightface pointclasses

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, descriptive-set-theory

In the article *Projectively wellordered inner models*, Steel proves the following theorem (4.12):

*Theorem*: Let $n < \omega$ and suppose $\mathcal{M}_n^{\sharp}$ exists. Let $\delta=\delta^1_{n+2}$. Then for any $A \subseteq \omega$, $A$ is $\Pi^1_{n+2}$ if and only if $A$ is $\Sigma_1$ over $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}$ if $n$ is odd and  $A$ is $\Sigma^1_{n+2}$ if and only if $A$ is $\Sigma_1$ over $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}$ if $n$ is even.

In the theorem it is implicit that $\Sigma_1$ means $\Sigma_1^{HC}$. The result is an extension of the so-called "Spector-Gandy companion theorem".

I was wondering if the result can be extended to sets $A \subseteq \omega^{\omega}$: for example can one have $A \subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ is $\Pi^1_{n+2}$ if and only if $A$ is $\Sigma_1$ over $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}$, where $\Sigma_1$ would be $\Sigma_1^A$, for some appropriate set $A$ ? (this would be the case where $n$ is odd). Notice this is in the lightface setting so the formulas would not involve any real numbers as parameters.

Secondly, can the result be extended to the boldface context: $A \subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ is $\bf\Pi^1_{n+2}$ if and only if $A$ is $\Sigma_1$ over $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}$, where $\Sigma_1$ would be $\Sigma_1^A$, for some appropriate set $A$  (case n is odd)? In this case formulas would involve real numbers as parameters.

Let me recall some definitions: $\mathcal{M}_n^{\sharp}$ is the mouse which has $n$ Woodin cardinals and a top measure (the sharp). It has a unique $(\omega, \omega_1)$ iteration strategy. $\delta^1_{n+2}$ is the supremum of the length of the $\Delta^1_{n+2}$ prewellorderings.

Edit: Following Andres suggestion, the $\mathcal{M}$ above should be taken to be $\mathcal{M}_n$, the mouse with $n$ Woodin cardinals.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{J}_\delta^\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: $\mathcal{M}$ is a mouse so it has an extender sequence and it is built using Jensens' $J$ hierarchy (this is what the $\mathcal{J}$ refers to). $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}$ is an initial segment of $\mathcal{M}$ up to $\delta$ for $\delta < o(\mathcal{M})$. So basically, putting $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{J}^{\bf E}_{\alpha}$, where $\bf E$ is the extender sequence of $\mathcal{M}$ and $\alpha=o(\mathcal{M})$ then $\mathcal{J}^{\mathcal{M}}_{\delta}=\mathcal{J}^{\bf E}_{\delta}$.

Comment: So $\mathcal{J}^{\bf E}_{\alpha}$ denotes the structure $(J^{\bf E}_{\alpha}, \bf {E}|\alpha$, $E_{\alpha})$, $\bf {E}|\alpha$ is the extender sequence chopped at $\alpha$ and $E_{\alpha}$ is the $\alpha$-th extender on the sequence. I probably should add this to the above for clarity.

Comment: You are misquoting the paper. It is not an arbitrary $\mathcal M$ used here, but rather $\mathcal M_n$, the result of iterating the sharp extender of $\mathcal M_n^\sharp$ through the ordinals.

Comment: The intended generalization is false: $\mathcal M_n$ only has countably many reals. One can work with codes (definitions) for projective sets rather than the sets themselves to avoid this, and work not with $\mathcal M_n^\sharp$ but the relativized versions $\mathcal M_n^\sharp(x)$. The appropriate correctness results in this context are also addressed in section 4 of Steel's paper or, if you prefer a somewhat more modern presentation, see section 7 of his Handbook article.

Comment: @Andres: You're right in your first comment. I glossed over this point, but basically my $\mathcal{M}$ is $\mathcal{M(T)}$ when we iterate the top measure of $\mathcal{M}^{\sharp}_n$ through the ordinals and $\mathcal{M(T)}$ is the common part model (which is $\mathcal{M}_n$ as you point out). In your second comment, what do you mean by codes for projective sets? Do you mean reals which give the sets using a universal set?

Comment: I mean definitions (actual formulas), which is why I mention correctness, and the relativized mice so we can allow the needed parameters.

Comment: Ah I see, Thank you Andres. The correctness result you're referring to is Cor. 4.7, right? Also the formulas defining the projective sets will allow real parameters.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal M_n^\sharp$ is incorrect. You call it a proper class mouse in the previous to last paragraph, but it is actually countable. Anyway, "the proper class mouse with $n$ Woodin cardinals" is too vague to characterize $\mathcal M_n$, and adding "minimal" does not help.

Comment: Sorry about that, that's how I saw $\mathcal{M}_n$ defined (Grigor's paper:http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1389032273). I will correct this out. I guess that why I got the downvote: the question contains too many imprecisions.